# Replying to a specific user with Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy

I'm a complete noob when it comes to writing bots, so forgive me for my ignorance. I'd like to write a bot that automatically replies to a specific user. Every time they tweet, I want my bot to reply. I know for a fact that it's possible, I just don't know how to do it. I don't even know where to start. I created my Twitter app, I got the token access token codes, but what do I do next? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question with some code we can help you with. Please see [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidelines.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming at this point you already authenticated into tweepy.

```
toReply = "someonesTwitterName" #user to get most recent tweet
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#get the most recent tweet from the user
tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = toReply, count=1)

for tweet in tweets:
    api.update_status("@" + toReply + " This is what I'm replying with", in_reply_to_status_id = tweet.id)
```

Now if you want to create a bot you will have to check for new tweets every n seconds, if they have a tweet you haven't replied to yet, you would then reply to that tweet using something like this